# Can the hole concentration of cuprate superconductors generally be determined from lattice parameters?

Tags: superconductivity, x-ray-crystallography

As it is known, in [YBCO superconductors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttrium_barium_copper_oxide), lattice parameters are strongly dependent on hole concentration, so hole concentration can be determined by measuring the c-axis parameter, see e.g. [*"Oxygen determination from cell dimensions in
YBCO superconductors"*](https://web.njit.edu/~tyson/supercon_papers/Oxygen_Content_vs_c-axis.pdf) by Benzi, Bottizzo and Rizzi.

Is it similar for other cuprates, LSCO (La<sub>2-x</sub>Sr<sub>x</sub>CuO<sub>4</sub>) or [LBCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum_barium_copper_oxide), or are lattice parameters independent from doping level?

Comment: I compare XRD patterns of La2-xSrxCuO4 with different x. hard to say that there is some systematic shifting of peaks. 
also, I couldn't found any paper about this. It seems Sr effect of lattice parameters is not sizable.

If one has any experience or idea, glad to  read him/her comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is paper where lattice parameters dependence on x is shownn:
https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.49.4163

This graph I extact from this paper:
[image]